# Average value of an integral over a vector space

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

How do we find the average value of an integral over a vector space for example $\Bbb R^2$ so normally to find the average value of an integral over a region you find $$\frac{\displaystyle\iint_R f(x,y)dxdy}{\text{Area of  the  region}} $$
but what if the region is $\Bbb R^2$ how do I evaluate the average value of the integral?

Comment: What is wrong with the formula you provided?

Comment: If $R=\mathbb{R}^2$ you may consider $$\lim_n{1\over (2n)^2}\int_{-n}^n\int_{-n}^n f(x,y)dx\,dy $$ provided the limit exists. The value will be $0$ if the function is absolutely integrable over $\mathbb{R}^2.$ So it makes sense for function which are not absolutely integrable.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Or even $\displaystyle\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\pi R^2}\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}f(r,\theta)\,r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: @Abezhiko You should divide by $\pi R^2,$ not by $4\pi R^2.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc My bad, thanks for the remark.